# Eccentricity change in an elliptical orbit after change in force direction?

Tags: conic-sections, classical-mechanics

An object is moving in an ellipse of eccentricity *e* under the action of a force *F* towards a force. When the object is at the periapsis, *F* is suddenly transferred to the other focus. Show that eccentricity of the new orbit is $\frac{e(3+e)}{(1-e)}$.

**Approach**

Right as the object comes to the periapsis, the energy equation is:

$\varepsilon_1 = \frac{V^2 _p}{2} + \frac{\mu}{r_p} = -\frac{\mu}{2a} $.

I am assuming that the energy will be conserved before and after the change in the direction of the force.

$\varepsilon_2 = \frac{V^2 _2}{2} + \frac{\mu}{r_2}$.

Other than this, I am not sure what I am supposed to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of question set on Physics Stack Exchange http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280699/eccentricity-change-in-an-elliptical-orbit-after-change-in-force-direction

Comment: FYI: An ellipse is not an [tag:elliptic-curve]. Please read the tag descriptions before using.